# How to customize message with multiple params in knockout validation?

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js

My code is as follows:

```
ko.validation.rules.between = {
    validator: function(value, params) {
        var min = params[0];
        var max = params[1];
        value = parseInt(value, 10);
        if (!isNaN(value)) {
            return value >= min && value <= max;
        }
        return false;   
    },
    message: 'Value must be between {0} and {1}'
};
ko.validation.registerExtenders()
// Use the rule
viewModel.someValue.extend({between: [10, 100]});
```

But when not valid, the error message will be:

> Value must be between 10, 100 and {1}

Comment: Which version of the validation plugin are you using? Here with version 2.0.2 is working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/kjffbkya/

Comment: It should work starting [version 2.0.0](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Override-Error-Messages)

Comment: Thanks. The problem is the version and it works with version 2.0.2.

Comment: If OP would retag the question with the specific version used to repro the problem, and @nemesv would convert his comment into an answer, this question would increase in value for others with the same issue.